# Making sure column data has 1 to 1 match

Tags: python, pandas

In the table below, I am trying to make sure 1 student ID has 1 name. For example, `Student_ID` `101` has 2 names associated with it (Adam and Bob). So I want to get the `Student_ID`.

The result I need would be ID: 101 (because it has 2 names associated with it).

```
Student_ID  Name    Text 
101 Adam    234
200 Cat 45645
101 Adam    5476456
200 Cat 34
101 Bob 456
200 Cat 456
200 Cat 4356
300 Cat 356
```

How can I proceed with this problem? I don't think we can use a dictionary. I just need a direction to move forward with solving this problem.

Comment: So, did the suggested solution help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping by `Student_ID` and applying the function `nunique` will count the number of names by ID:

```
df.groupby('Student_ID')['Name'].nunique()
```

You can either filter the result above, or filter the original dataframe directly:

```
df.groupby('Student_ID').filter(lambda group: group['Name'].nunique() > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is a great idea. use it to map student name to a count of how many times its been seen.

```
import csv

students = {}

with open('test.csv') as fp:
    next(fp) # skip header
    for row in csv.reader(fp, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True):
        if row:
            student = row[1]
            if student in students:
                students[student] += 1
            else:
                students[student] = 1

for student, count in students.items():
    if count > 1:
        print(student, "present mutliptle times")
```

Its such a great idea that python implements one for you in `collections.Counter`. Give that class an iterator and it will create a dictionary counting how many times a given value is seen in that iterator.

```
import collections

with open('test.csv') as fp:
    next(fp) # skip header
    students = collections.Counter(row[1] 
        for row in csv.reader(fp, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
        if row)

for student, count in students.items():
    if count > 1:
        print(student, "present mutliptle times")
```